# Microsoft DPM, What are the Type Values in the Alert Table (SQL Backend)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scdpm

Currently I have a PowerShell script which hooks into the SQL Backend of DPM and queries the list of unresolved alerts.

In the table `tbl_AHP_Alerts` There is a field called `Type`.

This `Type` Field refers to the situation of why the alert was triggered.
For example, a `Type` of `25` corresponds to the issue 'Recovery Point Failed'

I need to take appropriate action according to this `Type` Field. Does anyone know where there is a list of what this field ties up to? i.e. What the other numbers represent?

Comment: If you already have System Center DPM, you likely also have System Center Operations Manager available to you as well, which has excellent alerting for DPM failures. Just food for thought.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed a more bespoke solution in this instance

Answer (score 2):

I have found a list hosted on Microsoft TechNet @ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757766.aspx

-1 
RestoreDBAlert

0
NullType

1
AgentIncompatibleAlert

2
AgentUnreachableAlert

5
MediaVerificationFailedAlert

6
MediaEraseFailedAlert

7
DetailedInventoryFailedAlert

8
MediaDecommissionedAlert

9
MediaDataEraseAlert

10
FreeMediaThresholdAlert

11
DataSetCopyFailedAlert

12
BackupToTapeFailedAlert

13
BackupToTapeCatalogFailedAlert

14
LibraryDriveAlert

15
LibraryNotAvailableAlert

16
LibraryNotWorkingEfficientlyAlert

17
MediaRequiredAlert

18
ReplicaInitializationInProgressAlert

19
SynchronizationFailedAlert

20
StopProtectionFailedAlert

21
RecoveryInProgressAlert

22
RecoveryPartiallySuccessfulAlert

23
RecoverySuccessfulAlert

24
RecoveryFailedAlert

25
ShadowCopyFailedAlert

26
ReplicaInMissingStateAlert

27
ReplicaInInvalidStateAlert

28
PartialDeployedClusterAlert

29
AgentTaskFailAlert

30
SqmOptInAlert

31
DiskThresholdCrossedAlert

32
VerificationInProgressAlert

33
DiskMissingAlert

34
CatalogThresholdCrossedAlert

35
DatasetDataVerificationFailed

36
SCDiskThresholdCrossedAlert

37
ConfigureProtectionFailedAlert

38
ReplicaManualLoadPendingAlert

39
ReplicaInitializationPendingAlert

40
CertificateExpiringAlert

41
EvalShareInquiryAlert

42 
ShadowCopyConsolidationRequired